# Automatically adjusting winform size and its controls position to various screen sizes and resolutions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a winforms application written in Visual Studio 2010, C#.  My issue is trying to maintain the application for different screen resolution sizes. I can't scale it, since the layout of each of the controls are optimally suited for the aspect and size of the attached screen.  Currently I maintain 3 different code, designer, and resx files for each (WF-1920, WF-1024, WF-800 for a 7", 10", and 24" screen, respectively).   In the project, I copy the appropriate winform (cs, designer, resx) to the application solutions folder and rename it to WF.cs, WF-designer.cs, and WF.resx and make my changes, then build the application for each screen size. I have a pre-loader application that checks the screen size and then runs the application exe that is appropriate to it.   This obviously, is very difficult to maintain.  They all could utilize the same code file controls, methods, and events, but depending on the screen size, some are invisible, and others not used.

How can I have a single code file, that I can use and change the different form layouts without having to copy and rename each time I want to make a change?

Comment: did ya try **FormWindowState.Maximized** set property to that

Comment: @user3044638: Do you use Anchor and Dock Properties?

Comment: Try looking up the MVVM pattern And maybe dependency injection too..

Comment: The Dock and Anchor will not work, since the control locations are quite different for each screen size. In addition, certain aspect ratios must be maintained, which they will not if just scaling, that's why maximize or those properties do not work for me.

Comment: What about having some kind of table containing the following properties for each of the affected controls: Visible, Location and Size? This table should then have one column for each of the screen resolutions you will target. When the current screen resolution has been detected on startup, you lookup in the table where and how to position the controls, and if they should be shown at all. Or, instead of a table you could have a settings file for each resolution.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, however, it would be nice to be able to have use of the designer and be able to 'view' the appearance so I can easily make changes visually.  I have hundreds of controls in this application, with several grouped  panels. The panel size and placement within each group will be different for each screen size.  But I do like the suggestion.